# Fullscreen widget

Tags: c++, linux, qt, widget, fullscreen

How can I make my widget fullscreen? I've tried something like this:

```
void MainWindow::SetFullScreen()
{
    // Make our window without panels
    this->setWindowFlags( Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::Tool | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint );
    // Resize refer to desktop
    this->resize( QApplication::desktop()->size() );

    this->setFocusPolicy( Qt::StrongFocus );
    this->setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose, true);

    qApp->processEvents();
    show();
    this->setFocus();
}
```

But widget isn't over system panels. Any another ideas?

OS: Linux

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`QWidget::showFullScreen()` is what you need - works great under Linux+Windows in my projects for years - but be careful, there shouldn't be two calls of this function (eg. first call of `QMainWindo->showFullScreen()` and then `MyWidget->showFullScreen()`).

ciao,
Chris

Comment: Unless "MyWidget" is another window MyWidget->showFullScreen() won't do anything.

Comment: how about multiple screen setups with XRandr,Eyefinity or Xinerama? Does this work properly?

Comment: multiple screens should work - but by default showFullscreen() only uses one screen - but you can determine the whole desktop size (inluding multiple monitors/screens) and set the geometry manually...

Comment: Fullscreen works but i have a white frame around my window - how can i remove it?

Comment: Normally you don't have a frame - only if the widget (QFrame or derived class) which called showFullScreen() has a FrameStyle != NoFrame, then you'll see a frame... so just check your fullscreen widget end ensure that you don't have, for example a QLabel with a frame.

Comment: The white frame in my case came from a border in the layout manager used in the central widget. Removed it with - layout->setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

Answer (score 12):

This code will allow you to set a full screen by double clicking and to return back to the normal view by double clicking again.

```
void myWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
  QWidget::mouseDoubleClickEvent(e);
  if(isFullScreen()) {
     this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowMaximized);
  } else {
     this->setWindowState(Qt::WindowFullScreen);
  }
}
```