# How to fullscreen a QGLWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, fullscreen, qglwidget

I am new to OpenGL and Qt, and I am learning both simultaneously(3 days already:). I couple of years ago I did some exmerimenting with DirectX and I clearly remember that it was possible to make a full-screen window there. By full-screen I mean really full-screen, even without the top part where you have the close fullscreen and minimize buttons.

I have this program so far:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QGLWidget w;
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

What should I add to it to make w full-screen?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fullscreen widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246825/fullscreen-widget)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[showFullScreen()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#showFullScreen)

Although I don't want to just say RTM - the [Qt online documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/index.html) really is excellent.

Comment: Thanks! :) And how do I restore its size to default later? Calling show upon showFullScreen doesn't help

Comment: That answer is a link to documentation that says "To return from full-screen mode, call showNormal()"  :)

Comment: @Arnold: Thanks again. I am really sorry for such newbie question. I assume that learning to correctly and efficiently use the documentation is a part of learning of the particular technology :)

Comment: No worries. I think half of Qt's success is due to its documentation :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
QGLWidget w(0L,Qt::SplashScreen);
w.showFullScreen();
```

However, I don't remember if Qt::SplashScreen is the good flag.